# Field packing into a single "byte param" field

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, web3py

I'm experimenting with Aave's FlashLiqudidationAdapter.sol, which requires a `params` field which contains `address,address,address,uint256,bool`, but whenever I encode and submit the transaction it gets reverted at `_decodeParameters`, which is a function, which unpacks said `params` within the smart contract. I'm unsure what I am doing wrong. Here are my plain (non-encoded) params:

```
"0xb7c325266ec274feb1354021d27fa3e3379d840d,0xff682ff79feb2c057ec3ff1e083efdc66f9b37fb,0x1ea0B089673720e210552c624aFff9d67F8b1535,-1,0"
```

Here are the params encoded):

```
b"000000000000000000000000b7c325266ec274feb1354021d27fa3e3379d840d000000000000000000000000ff682ff79feb2c057ec3ff1e083efdc66f9b37fb0000000000000000000000001ea0b089673720e210552c624afff9d67f8b1535ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
```

Here's the whole transaction:

```
tx = flash_loan.requestFlashLoan(["0xb7c325266ec274feb1354021d27fa3e3379d840d"], [(2.8134148508367174 / 2) * 1e18], [0], b"000000000000000000000000b7c325266ec274feb1354021d27fa3e3379d840d000000000000000000000000ff682ff79feb2c057ec3ff1e083efdc66f9b37fb0000000000000000000000001ea0b089673720e210552c624afff9d67f8b1535ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", {"gas_limit": "200000", "gas_price": Wei('4 gwei'), "from": account1, "allow_revert": True, "nonce": 46})
```

Lastly, here's the referenced `_decodeParams` function where the revert is taking place as referenced earlier

```
 /**
   * @dev Decodes the information encoded in the flash loan params
   * @param params Additional variadic field to include extra params. Expected parameters:
   *   address collateralAsset The collateral asset to claim
   *   address borrowedAsset The asset that must be covered and will be exchanged to pay the flash loan premium
   *   address user The user address with a Health Factor below 1
   *   uint256 debtToCover The amount of debt to cover
   *   bool useEthPath Use WETH as connector path between the collateralAsset and borrowedAsset at Uniswap
   * @return LiquidationParams struct containing decoded params
   */
  function _decodeParams(bytes memory params) internal pure returns (LiquidationParams memory) {
    (
      address collateralAsset,
      address borrowedAsset,
      address user,
      uint256 debtToCover,
      bool useEthPath
    ) = abi.decode(params, (address, address, address, uint256, bool));

    return LiquidationParams(collateralAsset, borrowedAsset, user, debtToCover, useEthPath);
  }
}
```

https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2/blob/master/contracts/adapters/FlashLiquidationAdapter.sol#L173-L184

**Note, that I am using solidity compiler version ^0.6.12.**

Comment: the function expects a uint, but you're passing -1 as the argument?

Comment: @wxker this is valid in solidity ^0.6.12. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148129/encoding-1-as-a-uint256

Answer (score 1):

Solidity expects type byte to start with a `0x`, so the correct byte string to pass as the `params` should be as follows:

```py
b"0x000000000000000000000000b7c325266ec274feb1354021d27fa3e3379d840d000000000000000000000000ff682ff79feb2c057ec3ff1e083efdc66f9b37fb0000000000000000000000001ea0b089673720e210552c624afff9d67f8b1535ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
```